# My MVC is not displaying the correct view when calling MakeRequest Method

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, model-view-controller

I have the class below:

```
public class Product
{
        [JsonProperty("image")]
        public string ImageURL { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("superDepartment")]
        public string SuperDepartment { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("tpnb")]
        public long TPNB { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ContentsMeasureType")]
        public string ContentsMeasureType { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("UnitOfSale")]
        public int UnitOfSale { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public IEnumerator<string> LstDescription { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("AverageSellingUnitWeight")]
        public decimal AverageSellingUnitWeight { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("UnitQuantity")]
        public string UnitQuantity { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("id")]
        public long ID { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ContentsQuantity")]
        public int ContentsQuantity { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("department")]
        public string Department { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("price")]
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("unitprice")]
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

I have the method on the productController:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> MakeRequest(string q)// worked 
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "56ac439a92694577a2779f3d0ee0cd85");

        var uri = string.Format("https://dev.tescolabs.com/grocery/products/?query={0}&offset={1}&limit={2}", q, 0, 10);

        var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);          
        string body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Product myoutput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(body);
        }
        return View(body);
    }
```

and I have the model below:

For some reason when I call the method `MakeRequest` it just shows the information as a string and an error saying Server Error as per picture below we can see the information from the api but it is showing as a string.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuISz.png)
The information from the api it should be showing on the table below:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTmV5.png)

How to show the data on the table? Or better how to convert the json array to a net object?

I know there is something missing in the part below of my method:

```
Product myoutput = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(body);
```

Comment: your model with response json model not match.

Comment: Hi Sinan, thank you very much please could you give me more information about the model model not matching response json?

Answer (score 0):

You're passing json string to your View instead of your deserialized Product.
I assume your View expects model of type Product.

The return statement of MakeRequest action should be `return View(myOutput);`

Comment: Thank you very much Vilius,

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you in a simple way.

Your json model

> -uk
>   --ghs
>   ---products
>   ----results

```
{
  "uk" : {
    "ghs" : {
      "products": {
        "input_query": "babana",
        "output_query": "banana",
        "filters": {},
        "queryPhase": "post_primary",
        "totals": {
          "all": 109,
          "new": 1,
          "offer": 47
        },
        "config": "default",
        "results": [
          {
            "image": "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/000/0261480000000/IDShot_90x90.jpg",
            "superDepartment": "Fresh Food",
            "tpnb": 50502269,
            "ContentsMeasureType": "KG",
            "name": "Tesco Bananas Loose",
            "UnitOfSale": 3,
            "description": [ "To help ensure the banana farms we source from are best in class we, and our", "suppliers, now work closely with the Rainforest Alliance, an international", "non profit organisation that works to conserve biodiversity and ensure", "sustainable livelihoods worldwide.", "The Rainforest Alliance Certified&#8482; seal on our bananas   a green frog nestled", "in a circle &#8211; helps us to tell the story of how they are sustainably sourced,", "and assure customers we are sourcing from responsibly managed farms." ],
            "AverageSellingUnitWeight": 2.402,
            "UnitQuantity": "KG",
            "id": 275280804,
            "ContentsQuantity": 1,
            "department": "Fresh Fruit",
            "price": 0.76,
            "unitprice": 0.76
          },
          {
            "image": "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/875/0000010001875/IDShot_90x90.jpg",
            "superDepartment": "Fresh Food",
            "tpnb": 65728590,
            "ContentsMeasureType": "SNGL",
            "name": "Tesco Ripe Bananas 5 Pack",
            "UnitOfSale": 1,
            "AverageSellingUnitWeight": 0.862,
            "UnitQuantity": "EACH",
            "id": 266419328,
            "ContentsQuantity": 5,
            "department": "Fresh Fruit",
            "price": 0.9,
            "unitprice": 0.18
          },
          {
            "image": "http://img.tesco.com/Groceries/pi/416/0000003251416/IDShot_90x90.jpg",
            "superDepartment": "Fresh Food",
            "tpnb": 77427870,
            "ContentsMeasureType": "SNGL",
            "name": "Tesco Small Bananas 6 Pack",
            "UnitOfSale": 1,
            "description": [ "Small Bananas", "Tesco Small Bananas" ],
            "AverageSellingUnitWeight": 0.965,
            "UnitQuantity": "EACH",
            "id": 285157326,
            "ContentsQuantity": 6,
            "department": "Fresh Fruit",
            "price": 0.9,
            "unitprice": 0.15
          }
        ],
        "suggestions": []
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you look at the above json result, you need a more comprehensive model.

For this you can enter the json result into a model here. [look here](http://json2csharp.com/)

or keep the result object from its current state with dynamic.

```
   string body = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            dynamic content = JObject.Parse(body);

            var products = content.uk.ghs.products.results;
```